# class row in style.php

Tags: php, html, css

Im working on a article:
I want 3 in one row. I know how to do it with stype, but i dont know how to do it with style.php.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYcpx.png)

This is only the part of code but I need to properly implement grid:

```
echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row padding">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">';
            echo '<div class="card">';
                echo '<img src="' . UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '"';
                    echo '<div class="card-body">';
                        echo '<h6 class="card-title">';
                            echo '&laquo;';
                                 echo $row['naslov'];
```

//style.php

```
<?php 
    header('content-type:text/css');
    $grid='grid';
?>

.container { 
    display:  <?=$grid?>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are dealing the problem really improperly.
I don't really get why you need to use a variable named `$grid` while you can directly pass the grid attribute to your `.container`.
You don't have do complicate it like this.
What I would do in your case would be the next thing:

I would create a class named `.grid` like:

```
   .grid {
       display: grid !important;
     }
```

As for the rest I would put it like this:
Please provide more info as regards how you extract out the `$row` variable data.
The layout per se, would have to be like this in order for you to have 3 cards in a row. Hope that helps you. Cheers

```
<div class="container grid">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div class="card">
                <img src="<?= '"'. UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '"' alt="whatever 
            you need" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                       <h6 class="card-title">
                          <?php  echo '&laquo;' . " ". $row['naslov']; ?>
                       </h6>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div class="card">
                <img src="<?= '"'. UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '"' alt="whatever 
            you need" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                       <h6 class="card-title">
                          <?php  echo '&laquo;' . " ". $row['naslov']; ?>
                       </h6>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div class="card">
                <img src="<?= '"'. UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '"' alt="whatever 
            you need" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                       <h6 class="card-title">
                         <?php  echo '&laquo;' . " ". $row['naslov']; ?>
                       </h6>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because I use style.php and ordinary css doesnt work or I dont know how to use it