# Display 3 articles in same line with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css

Im using php and mysqli database, I know how to pull information but it always put articles one bellow another:

Article 1

Article 2

Article 3

Insted of Article1, Article2, Article3

```
<section class="politique container">

    <?php
        $query="SELECT*FROM projekt WHERE arhiva=0 AND kategorija='politique' LIMIT 3";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbo, $query);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {


            echo'<article>';
                echo '<div class="container">';
                    echo '<div class="row padding>';
                        echo'<div class="col-md-12 ">';
                            echo '<div class="card col-md-4">';
                                    echo '<img  class="card-img-top" src="' . UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '">';
                                    echo '<div class="card-body">';
                                        echo '<h6 class="card-title">';
                                            echo $row['naslov'];
                                        echo '</h6>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                        echo'<div class="ispod">';
                                            echo $row['datum']; 
                                        echo '</div>'; 
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';                 
                echo '</div>';
            echo'</article>';
        }?>
</section>
```

I included in condition only 3 articles per line but somehow it probably enters new container every time so that articles are bellow one of another.

Comment: That’s because you are creating a new `container` and `row` element for each item _inside_ your loop, whereas those should of course be _outside_ of it.

Comment: Please don't mix PHP and HTML like this: https://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your previous two? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263214/class-row-in-style-php
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270275/how-to-properly-display-this-php-block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [class row in style.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263214/class-row-in-style-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `while` loop so it happens WITHIN the row element.

```
<section class="politique container">

    <?php
        $query="SELECT*FROM projekt WHERE arhiva=0 AND kategorija='politique' LIMIT 3";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbo, $query);




            echo'<article>';
                echo '<div class="container">';
                    echo '<div class="row padding>';
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '<div class="card col-md-4">';
                                    echo '<img  class="card-img-top" src="' . UPLPATH . $row['slika'] . '">';
                                    echo '<div class="card-body">';
                                        echo '<h6 class="card-title">';
                                            echo $row['naslov'];
                                        echo '</h6>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                        echo'<div class="ispod">';
                                            echo $row['datum']; 
                                        echo '</div>'; 
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    echo '</div>';                 
                echo '</div>';
            echo'</article>';
     ?>
</section>
```

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments on your question, there is a cleaner way to mix php and html in your code;

```
<?php
  $query="SELECT*FROM projekt WHERE arhiva=0 AND kategorija='politique' LIMIT 3";
  $result=mysqli_query($dbo, $query);
?>
<section class="politique container">
  <article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row padding">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
          <div class="card col-md-4">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo UPLPATH.$row['slika'] ?>">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['naslov']; ?></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="ispod">
              <?php echo $row['datum']; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Now I have problem with closing <?php ?> because last 3 divs are not in php anymore

Comment: Please select a correct answer and vote accordingly :)

Comment: I cant, I have bellow 15 reputation so my votes wont be displayed publicly